# Calculating x for a given probability p

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, gaussian

An energy-saving lamp lights up an average of 10,000 hours before it fails, with a standard deviation of 800 hours.

Which lighting duration is not exceeded by 80% of the lamps?

My approach would be to take the Gaussian distribution

$p = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$

and transform to $x$ where $p = 80$.

Are there any other approaches?

Comment: How do you know the times are normally distributed? If they are, you would use $p = 0.80,$ not $80.$

Comment: Without knowing the probability distribution, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: [Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) gives you some information.